# Consumers = CALCULATE(COUNT('Global-Superstore'[Customer ID]('Global-Superstore'[Category]="Consumer")))

Tags: dax

Interested in learning the precise formula for the new measure.

getting Error.
Kindly direct me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Consumers = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Global-Superstore'),[Category]="Consumer")

the fun part is if you're counting only "active" customers. (The ones that are purchasing in a given time frame). Then you do a distinct count of CustomerID's in the fact table:

DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales'[CustomerID])